# What is wrong with background video layer positioning?

Tags: html, css

Tried to make a website menu with three full screen [background overlays](http://codepen.io/nemmoj/pen/pybxKp), but background video (underlying) in that menu is shifted down. What is wrong with positioning markup?

**CSS:**

```
.videoContainer {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    //padding: 20px;
    border-radius: 1px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.videoContainer video {
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    z-index: -5;
}
.videoContainer .overlay-vid-1 {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: -1;
    background: black;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

P.s. - tried playing with `z-index`, `position:` and `<div>` reordering, but no luck.

P.p.s. - yes, i know, this is not the whole code, but system informer said that I can`t paste whole code, so there is a link to codepen, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the position of your video to `position: absolute;` because it's being pushed down by the `.overlay-content`. Try changing your CSS to look like this:

**CSS**

```
.videoContainer video {
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    position: absolute; /* Change to absolute */
    top: 0px;           /* Set top to 0px */
    z-index: -5;
}
```

[**Updated CodePen**](http://codepen.io/Hunter377/pen/zqBygP)

Comment: Thank you Hunter, updated my code with that update, but now semi-transparent overlay between video and text has gone (text background), text is hardly readable now. Could you see what should be done to bring him back?

Comment: @ne.mmoj What overlay are you talking about? I noticed overlay difference between your code and mine. I think the text is harder to read because it's now in front of a lighter section of the video. You could try adding some `text-shadow` to your text to make it more readable.

Comment: I agree, `text-shadow` and `text-background` are good option, but...
`.videoContainer .overlay-vid-1 {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: -4;
    background: black;
    opacity: 0.5;
}`
is no longer visible,

it is placed in html as `<div class="overlay-vid-1"></div>`

Comment: If you look at my CodePen vs your CodePen. You'll see that the overlay exists on mine, but yours does not have it. I just went through your CodePen and saw you had an extra `}` after your `.videoContainer video` in your CSS. Remove that and you should be good to go.

Comment: Yes, you are right, it might have happend when I paste changes that you adviced. Thank you, thank you very much, now everything is perfect  :)